# getting `sh: 1: exec: nest: not found` error deploying nestjs to google app engine

Tags: node.js, docker, google-app-engine, nestjs

I am trying to deploy my nestjs application to google app engine, but I get `sh: 1: exec: nest: not found` error

my package.json

```
    "main": "dist/main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
        "build": "nest build",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
        "start": "nest start",
        "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
        "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
        "start:prod": "node dist/main",
        "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
        "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
        "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
        "gcp-build": "npm run build",
        "ae:deploy": "gcloud app deploy --quiet",
        "ae:browse": "gcloud app browse",
        "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    }
```

DockerFile

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g @nestjs/cli@8

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:prod" ]
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: default

instance_class: F1

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
```

CloudBuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  args:
  - build
  - "--tag=gcr.io/cmor-baas-dev/kafka-connector:latest"
  - "--file=Dockerfile"
  - .  
images:
- "gcr.io/cmor-baas-dev/kafka-connector"
timeout: 1800s
```

[image: npm run ae:deploy]

[image: logs]

I think both Dockerfile and CloudBuild.yaml files are ignored (I am new to Google app engine, not sure do we need those files)

### Update

Based on [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies),

> All dependencies that you define under the devDependencies field are
> ignored and do not get installed for your app in App Engine.

So I moved `@nestjs/cli` to `dependencies` in my package.json, still same error

Comment: @PJoe see accepted answer below

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In case someone else came to this post looking for answer:

Two changes are needed:

1- update start script to `"start": "node dist/main.js"`

2- move `@nestjs/cli` from `devDependency` to `dependency`

Then it starts working

p.s Neither CloudBuild.yaml or Dockerfile is needed

Comment: Thank you so much, this did solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you came here looking for a solution because you are trying to deploy nestjs app on render.com and having this same issue, today is your lucky day.

1. Uninstall @nestjs/cli as devDependency and install dependency.
2. Set start script to;  "start:prod": "node dist/main"
3. Set node version in package.json as:

   "engines": { "node": "x.x.x"//e.g "18.16.0" }

Then push and deploy on render; it should work.